# How to redirect external link in a Docker container to local service

Tags: docker, redirect, docker-compose

I'm still early on my Docker journey and I'm trying to 'Dockerise' an existing UI/API/DB web app where the UI & API/DB are on two different servers. It's gone fairly well so far and my docker-compose fires up services for UI, API & DB (and phpMyAdmin) just fine. I know that those services can communicate inherently using service names as host names due to the default networking method of Docker.

The UI (an Angular codebase) makes various calls to https://api.myproject.com which works fine in the live sites but isn't ideal in my Docker version as I want it to reach my API service in the container not the API live site.

I know that I can edit the code on the UI container and replace calls to https://api.myproject.com with calls to 'api' but that's inconvenient and lacks portability if I want to redeploy on different servers (as it is now) in future.

Is it possible for a container to redirect all POST/GET etc. for a URL to a container service? I thought the `--add-host` might do something like this but it seems to want an IP address rather than a service name.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT [clarification]**
My issue lies in the UI page (HTML/JS) that the user sees in the browser. When the page is loaded it throws some GET requests to the API URL and that's what I was hoping to redirect to the container API service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use network aliases for the given container and those can override an existing fqdn.

Here is a 2mn crafted example:

**`docker-compose.yml`**

```yaml
---
services:
  search_engine:
    image: nginx:latest
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - google.com
          - www.google.com

  client:
    image: alpine:latest
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

You can start this project with:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Then log into the client container with

```
docker-compose exec client sh
```

And try to reach your `search_engine` service with either of the following

```
wget http://search_engine
wget http://google.com
wget http://www.google.com
```

In all cases you will get the default `index.html` page of a brand new installed nginx server.

Comment: This is excellent info & it does what I asked, thanks so much. However I realise now that I asked the wrong question... My issue is that the UI HTML page (Angular app) from the container that the users sees is sending requests to https://api.myproject.com. Since that is in the browser on the host machine it won't (and can't I guess) be affected by any container settings. I suspect I'll have to edit the code after all but I'm delighted to learn something that I think will be handy in future. Thanks @Zeitounator

Comment: You could actually run a browser from a container participating to the same compose project and that would. That could be suited for your local dev machine. But that wont fix anything for a CI environment you would access remotely.